# R: RScript Vector as argument

Tags: r, vector, command-line, rscript

i am using the preinstalled package RScript in R.

I want to call the following R-Script with the name 'test.R' from the command prompt:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")
a

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
b <- as.vector(args[1])
b
```

I use the following command:

```
RScript test.R c("d","e","f")
```

This creates following output:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c"
[1] "c(d,e,f)"
```

As you see, the first (and only) argument is interpreted as a String, then converted to a 1-dimensional vector. How can the argument be interpreted as a vector?

Sidenote: Of course the items of the vector could be separated into several arguments, but in my final project, there will be more than one vector-argument. And to implement something like this is my last resort:

```
RScript test.R "d" "e" "f" END_OF_VECTOR_1 "g" "h" "i" END_OF_VECTOR_2 "j" "k" "l"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use comma-separated lists.

On the command line:

```
RScript test.R a,b,c d,e,f g,h,i j
```

In your code:

```
vargs <- strsplit(args, ",")
vargs
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "d" "e" "f"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "g" "h" "i"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "j"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up something like `a = "c(1,2,3)"` with:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(substr(a,3,nchar(a)-1), ",")))
```

which works fine as long as script will always be passed a properly formatted string, and you are aware of the expected format. In the RScript arguments, the `c()` part should not be listed, simply give it a quoted comma-separated list.

Answer (score -1):

@flodel thanks for your answer, thats one way to do it. Beside that, I have found a workaround for my problem.

The following code in the file 'test.R' stores the arguments in 'args'. The text in 'args' is then evaluated to normal R expressions and as an output, a and b are given.

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
eval(parse(text=args))
a
b
```

The code can be called in the command prompt as follows:

```
RScript test.R a=5 b=as.vector(c('foo', 'bar'))
```

Comment: Yes, it's another approach but `eval(parse(text=...))` is very frowned upon among the R community. Imagine what would happen if a malicious user passed in `q("no")` as an argument. Or worse `system("rm -rf /*")`. Do not attempt that second example, it will try to delete everything on your machine... On the other hand, passing arguments as comma-separated lists is safe and very common when writing scripts.